# Is it possible to avoid synchronizing certain contacts from Salesforce into Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, contact, marketing-cloud-connect

Some contacts are not supposed to be reachable by Marketing Cloud. They are created for other, internal purposes, not related to marketing at all.

Is it possible to avoid the synchronization of **certain** contacts with Marketing Cloud?

For example, by using a custom checkbox field on the Contact record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference this doc '[Create Synchronized Data Sources in Contact Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_creating_and_interacting_with_synchronized_data_sources.htm&type=5)'

> Filter the synchronized records you choose to import using the Records Collection buttons.
>
> - To import all records, select All records.
> - To import only records with an email address, select All records with
>   an email address.
> - To import only records created after a specified date, select All
>   records created since and specify the date.
> - To use a Boolean filter to import records, select All records with
>   and enter the Boolean value. Select an attribute, set the operator,
>   and choose True or False.